# Job hunting during months leading to graduate school

Tags: new-job, united-states

I was just told I've been accepted into a Business Analytics program. Since there is now ~4-6 months until I start how do I approach seeking employment in the interim, hopefully in a relevant field (Data Science). I would definitely not rule out returning to an employer I reach but as this is an accelerated program in a different state concurrent employment won't be much of an option and a summer internship does not work.

Answer (score 2):

> Since there is now ~4-6 months until I start how do I approach seeking
>   employment in the interim

Work with a temp agency.

Be honest about your situation so that they can find you one or more short term gigs to fill your free time.